# Examples can't connect to electroserver

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have recently downloaded Electro Server 5.4.1 from Electrotank, I have started the SAFEMODE.exe and I can see the console, I then log on to the server using the adobe AIR program, I then go and start the ChatLogger and it can't connect, has anyone got any ideas on why this isn't working?

Canvas

extra tags ElectroServer, ElectroTank

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and odds are you already got an answer to it on the Electrotank forums.  Just in case somebody else has a similar problem: the ChatLogger code example requires the ChatLogger extension to be deployed.

You should also check that you can connect using one of the SimpleChat code examples which do not need any extension.  If the Unity client works but AS3 doesn't, then you need to set your [Flash global security settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) to allow socket connections from that area of your hard drive.